# f# hashtag on Twitter is not valid

Tags: bug, twitter

[My question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/84695/brainfuck-interpreter-in-f) was tweeted with the automatic Code Review Twitter account.

[The tweet in question](https://twitter.com/StackCodeReview/status/579899466825732096) is using #f#, which isn't valid. It should use #fsharp, like #csharp [in this tweet](https://twitter.com/StackCodeReview/status/579807380684300288).

Comment: wow, good catch!